# Django - saving a form strips values so only the first word is saved

Tags: python, django, forms

I am currently working on a Django project and I have run into a problem when I save a form the values get stripped down so only the first word is saved.
I am quite sure that the problem is somewhere in the request.POST.get in the saveAuction method but haven't figured out how to fix it.

Here is my view.py:

```
from django.views import View
from .models import *
from .forms import *
from django.contrib import messages
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class createAuction(View):
    def get(self, request):
        form = createauction()
        return render(request,'auctionForm.html', {'form' : form, "title" : 
"Auction", "path" : "add"})

def post(self, request):
    form = createauction(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        auction_t = cd['title']
        auction_s = cd['seller']
        auction_d = cd['description']
        auction_mp = cd['min_price']
        auction_dl = cd['deadline']
        form = confAuct()
        return render(request, 'auctionForm.html', {
            "form": form,
            "title": "Confirm auction listing",
            "path" : "save",
            "auction_title" : auction_t,
            "auction_seller" : auction_s,
            "auction_desc" : auction_d,
            "auction_mip" : auction_mp,
            "auction_dL" : auction_dl
        })
    else:
        messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, "Not valid data")
        return render(request,'auctionForm.html', {'form' : form, "title" : 
"Auction"})

def saveAuction(request):
    option = request.POST.get('option', '')
    if option == 'Yes':
        a_title = request.POST.get('auction_title')
        a_seller = request.POST.get('auction_seller')
        a_desc = request.POST.get('auction_desc')
        a_mip = request.POST.get('auction_mip')
        a_dL = request.POST.get('auction_dL')
        auct = Auction(title=a_title, seller=a_seller, description=a_desc, 
min_price=a_mip, deadline=a_dL)
        auct.save()
        messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, "New auction has been 
saved")
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("auction-list"))
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("home"))


def listAuction(request):
    auctions = Auction.objects.all()
    return render(request, "auctionlist.html", {"title" : "Auction listing", 
"list" : auctions})
```

This is my forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from YAAS.models import Auction

class createauction(forms.Form):
    model = Auction
    title = forms.CharField(required=True)
    seller = forms.CharField(required=True)
    description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(), required=True)
    min_price = forms.IntegerField(required=True)
    deadline = forms.IntegerField(min_value=72, error_messages={"min_value":"Hours can not be less than 72!"}, required=True, help_text="How many hours until deadline? (min 72 h)")


class confAuct(forms.Form):
    CHOICES = [(x, x) for x in ("Yes", "No")]
    option = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES)
    t_title = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
```

This is my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.utils import timezone

# Create your models here.
class Auction(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=160)
    seller = models.CharField(max_length=160)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=420)
    min_price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    deadline = models.IntegerField(default=72)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: Show your `forms` and `views`. Are we supposed to guess the problem without seeing the code ?

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally submitted before I was done! Now it is all there.

Comment: What do you mean by this `only the first word is saved` ? can you give an example ?

Comment: This code doesn't make any sense. Why is `saveAuction` separate from the  `createAuction` view? The post method in that class doesn't do anything useful, but that's what should be doing the saving. And you are supposed to use the form to do the saving, that is the whole point of having one.

Comment: For example if the input is "This is the input" when I list the value later on the only thing that it shows it "This" and nothing more.

Comment: @DanielRoseman We have a requirement that there needs to be a confirmation page before saving so that's why I've got it like that. I've just started learning Django so I am not that familiar with how things work unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

I just solved this problem for myself today, not sure if this is what your problem was **checks notes ** 2 years and 7 months ago.... my issue was in my templates - form.html file. I didn't have my value attribute wrapped in quotes.

INCORRECT:
`<input id="publisher" type="text" name="publisher" value={{book.publisher}}>`

CORRECT:
`<input id="publisher" type="text" name="publisher" value="{{book.publisher}}">`